# Smart pointer to a subset of an array (c++11)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, c++11, smart-pointers

I have a function taking as argument a double pointer:

```
void myFunction(double **param)
```

I sometimes call this function by passing an array in which the elements point to a particular index of another array, e.g.:

```
double ** mat1 = new double*[2];
mat1[0] = new double[5];
mat1[1] = new double[5];
myFunction(mat1);
...
double **mat2 = new double*[2];
mat2[0] = &mat1[0][2];
mat2[1] = &mat1[1][4];
myFunction(mat2);
...
delete[] mat1[0];
delete[] mat1[1];
delete[] mat1;
delete[] mat2;
```

I would like to get rid of all the "new" operators in my code to facilitate memory management, either with standard containers or smart pointers. However, I cannot find a way to change the declaration of the function such that I can build an array with elements pointing to subsets of other arrays and pass it to the function (I would need a smart pointer type which would just act as a regular pointer).

mat1 must be of the same type as mat2 (they both can be passed as parameter of the function), so I cannot use a smart pointer of raw pointers.

Is there a way to do that?

Edit:
It seems that I can do:

```
std::unique_ptr< std::unique_ptr<double[]>[] > mat2(new std::unique_ptr<double[]>[2]);
mat2[0].reset(&mat1[0][2]);
mat2[1].reset(&mat1[1][4]);
```

Is that safe to do that? I suspect that there will be a delete on &mat1[0][2] and &mat1[1][4] when mat2 is destroyed?

Comment: Why are all those arrays dynamically allocated in the first place ? Why not a simple `double[2][5]` ?

Comment: This is an example, but sizes and indices are usually known only at runtime.

Comment: The function could instead take a container of something that can be used like a pointer. Until concepts come along, that's harder to specify, but a regular template parameter still works.

Comment: Why not pass use a vector of vectors (or some other container type)?

Comment: Jon-> because a vector contains its own data and cannot be just a reference to an index of another vector.

Comment: chris-> template seems a good idea to me. I will try that if my other solution does not work.

Comment: Well... template does not work because my function is virtual...

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, you should encapsulate you matrix in dedicated classes. I would use a class hierachy that could roughly be like this:

- a common base class that contains access functions regardless on where the memory lies and how it was obtained
- a concrete implementation that would allocate and deallocate memory (to use for mat1 in your example)
- a concrete implementation that allow for viewing a master matrix (to use for mat2 in your example)

That way you cleanly separate the allocation/deallocation question but still can transparently access to the original matrix and to its *view*.

I do not propose code here, because the concrete implementation will depend on whether the view must be informed that its *parent* was destroyed on not (the latter being simpler...), and on what are your exact requirements for common access and *view* definitions.

Comment: I will probably do that. I wanted to do something more basic to reduce the overhead, but I think that this is my only option. Templates had the advantage of allowing me to progressively convert my code.